# return the correlation matrix to initial values using R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I recently interested, is it possible to generate data on the a given value of coefficient of multiple determination in R. Now i want develop this question. How to return coefficients correlation from matrix to original value.
For example, i performed the correlation analysis
here the square matrix

```
X1           X2           X3        X4             X5
1           0,0254      -0,331     0,528         0,149
0,0254        1         -0,031    -0,414        -0,282
-0,331    -0,0312         1        0,159        -0,470
0,5288    -0,414         0,159      1           -0,218
0,149     -0,282        -0,47      -0,218          1
```

Is it possible in R to transform these correlation coefficients to original values?

The values for vars x1-x3 in range from 1-10, and the values for var x4-x5 in range from 11-20

Thank you

Comment: In general, that is not possible. You can try a simpler case with only X1 and X2.

Comment: Hi Patrick, one man decide this task in mathcad, but i want in R. He doesn't know R. I can give mathcad file. If it can help